# Can I photograph strangers voting at a polling station?

Tags: voting

Can a photo of strangers voting in a polling station be taken and put on
Facebook if their ballot is not showing how they voted.  Specifically in
Texas ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Texas law](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/EL/htm/EL.61.htm#A), Election code 61.014(b):

> A person may not use any mechanical or electronic means of recording images or sound within 100 feet of a voting station.

However, the punishment appears to be only this:

> The presiding judge may require a person who violates this section to turn off the device or to leave the polling place.